# ExpressJS and PassportJS Logout - Back Button

Tags: express, passport.js

Im using PassportJS and ExpressJS. I have a route for `logout`:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

However, when browser's back button is used, the page that is intented for logged user only, can still be displayed. How to avoid the said scenario? Thanks

Comment: Any Update on this? Would be really helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple ways to do it. The way I did it with passport in my app is that I have a have a redux reducer+action that calls on "api/current_user", which then returns a prop with a value true or false. True if the user is logged in, false if logged out.

```
class ChatContainer extends Component {
    renderContent() {
        switch (this.props.auth) {
            case null:
                return;
            case false:
                return <Redirect to="/" />;
            default:
                return [<ChatHeader key="1" />, <ChatWindow key="2" />];
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="chat-container">{this.renderContent()}</div>;
    }
}
```

The chat component, which is /chat, goes through the renderContent() logic before displaying anything. Anytime you want a parent component (the component responsible for the page through react-router-dom) only visible for logged in users, just use mapStateToProps -> this.props.auth.

I think since we are using oauth through our server, an anchor tag is appropriate here because the flow is basically react -> server (when we logout) -> back to your react login page. Hence using  would be inappropriate I believe. Sorry that an answer is a couple years late lol